# I can't get API3 QRNG to select a random enum value and mint an NFT based on this enum choice

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, vrf, enum

I tried to make a contract that mints a token from an enum of options https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/0ae15b021521c9583dde6c3cc782d4d3. This code fails at every turn. I started with the code from this video https://youtu.be/MFgMpA819DU. I didn't want the `strength` or `intelligence` to be generated dynamically, I just had an array of 3 character types that I wanted chosen at random. From my contract: `enum Classifier{FIRST, SECOND, THIRD}`. I used this contract as a reference for how to select at random from an enum https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/nft-mix/blob/main/contracts/AdvancedCollectible.sol. This Patrick Collins contract uses Chainlink but I swapped that out with API3. My contract is a complete failure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "My contract is a complete failure", What do yo mean exactly?, can you share the error?

Comment: It was just failing when I ran the `requestRandomSurfaceReachT1` function but I figured out what the problem was. It was an easy fix specific to API3. You need to run `setRequestParameters` parameters like this: `await contract.setRequestParameters(airnodeAddress, endpointId, chainSpecificAirnodeRelay)` before you run `requestRandomSurfaceReachT1`. My contract was correct but I passed the wrong value for `airnodeAddress` to `setRequestParameters`.